# Debian 8 - getnameinfo Failed Error - netstat

Tags: debian, netstat

I am experiencing a error/warning when running any netstat command on my Debian 8 machine.

One of the commands:-

> netstat | grep http | wc -l

The result:-

> getnameinfo failed
>
> getnameinfo failed
>
> getnameinfo failed
>
> getnameinfo failed
>
> getnameinfo failed
>
> 136

Why is it mentioning 'getnameinfo failed'? My server doesn't seem to be experiencing any issues.

Does anybody know a fix for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking me to check?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking me to check?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the error message indicates that some of the calls that `netstat` was making to `getnameinfo`(3) failed.

Ie, when `getnameinfo` was trying to look up the hostname corresponding to an IP address or the service name corresponding to a port number something failed in an unexpected manner.
(By default `netstat` shows names for both addresses and ports, also see the `-n` option)

If you care to try to track down what specifically is happening, it may be more helpful to see the errors in context (ie, drop the rest of the pipeline).